# Automatically flush data to database

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

99% certain this is just I don't know what to search for, so please feel free to point me at the correct terminology, but here goes.

I'm working on a project that uses Fluent NHibernate to store data in a SQLite backend.  it's extremely low load(a dozen or so reads on startup, then maybe a write or 2 a minute after that as a high load.)  I'm trying to go for more easy to write then anything else, so I want it so I can just change a property on an object and it'll automatically flush it to the backend.  Like I said, this is a very low load single user app, so even (worst case) 5 writes a second isn't gonna be that noticeable.

I do know that I could just set up saves in the property setters, but I'm trying to reduce redundant code, and that seems excessively redundant to me.

What I'm looking for is something like this

```
class MainConfig
{
    public virtual bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

and then be able to bind it to a control, so that changes to the control hit the property, and then it's saved.

Using a lot of extra code, I can accomplish it

```
class MainConfig
{
    bool _Enabled;
    public virtual bool Enabled
    {
        get { return _Enabled; }
        set { _Enabled = value; mainSession.Save() }
    }
}
```

where mainSession is a ISession that is static through the life of the app

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the perfect solution, but what I came up with is a T4 template that processes every config object and builds an proxy for it and all it's properties.

```
class MainConfigProxy : MainConfig
{
    public override Enabled
    {
         get { return base.Enabled; }
         set
         {
             base.Enabled = value;
             mainSession.Save();
         }
    }
}
```

and then builds a dictionary of type to type containing the base class and it's proxy.

Then my code checks that dictionary, and if there is a proxy, loads/instantiates that instead.  Not perfect, but saves a lot of typing

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is flush you session. The following example is from the [nHibernate Reference Documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing).

```
sess = sf.OpenSession();
ITransaction tx = sess.BeginTransaction();
sess.FlushMode = FlushMode.Commit; //allow queries to return stale state
Cat izi = (Cat) sess.Load(typeof(Cat), id);
izi.Name = "iznizi";
// execute some queries....
sess.Find("from Cat as cat left outer join cat.Kittens kitten");
//change to izi is not flushed!
...
tx.Commit(); //flush occurs
```

Please note that the documentation also states that there are other times an automated flush occurs (i.e. you wouldn't have to initiate it like the aforementioned example). **This is good news for you because that's actually kind of what you're looking for.**

Comment: I have just set up the code without doing flushes or anything, but it doesn't save.  I'm looking for pretty much instantly save, maybe through some kind of event or something.  Again, the issue is that I don't know NHibernate that well.

Comment: Please edit your question with a set of relevant snippets. For example, please post one of the models, and also a set of code the updates that model, that would give me a good overall view of how you use them. Of course change names as necessary to protect the innocent.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state what platform you're developing for, but in general since you're using data binding, the simplest approach is to attach an event handler to every control's changed event. When the changed event fires, the data bound object has changed and you can then flush the changes to the database.

Comment: Trying to avoid having hundreds of event bindings.  Ideal goal is just a simple save on property set

Comment: What platform? Typically you would loop through the controls and subscribe the changed event handler in a few lines of code. The alternative is to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your object, which is similar to your "lot of extra code" solution. The object should be persistence ignorant, i.e. not reference NHibernate. TANSTAAFL.

Comment: Don't see how INotifyPropertyChanged helps, as I thought that was notifying the controls and such of changes, and event handlers also don't solve the problem of code other then controls altering the properties

Comment: A proper implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged raises the PropertyChanged event when any property changes in the object. You can then attach a handler to the event and flush the session when it's raised. Implementing it is a lot of tedious work. Most applications give the user a save button that allows the user to notify the app when the data should be saved.